# Hide function-key labels in WordStar 4.0

Tags: wordstar

In WordStar 4.0, I know that I can hide the edit menu on the top of the screen with `^J^J`. But how can I hide the labels at the bottom of the screen that show what the function keys do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Exit WordStar.
2. Run the `wschange` installation program.
3. On the main menu, choose "D - WordStar".
4. On the next menu, choose "B - Editing settings".
5. On the next menu, chosse "A - Edit screen, help level".
6. Choose "J" to toggle whether function-key labels are shown.
7. Press "X" multiple times to return the the main menu and save the changes. Confirm that you are through making changes, then restart WordStar.

[image: Screenshot for wschange]